# Windows 8 GroupedItemsPage

Tags: xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, title

In a Windows 8 GroupedItemsPage, how can I change the title of each group? For example the default GroupedItemsPage has two groups and the titles of each group are "Group Title: 1" and "Group Title: 2" respectively. How can I change these titles?

Basically I want 4 groups where each group represents a different category and thus has an appropriate title :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in the DataModel/SampleDataSource.cs to see where all of the sample data, including group names are defined.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own Data model by checking out the sample one. If you aren't setting groups and stuff up dynamically, you can just change all the settings in the SampleDataSource.cs otherwise creating your own is probably a better option